# Two-directional replication of two separate Solr servers

Tags: indexing, solr, server, replication, solrcloud

I read about multi core or master slave in Solr but I am looking for complete replication of two separate Solr servers (Two-directional ). Where can I find a manual for doing that?

The two or more separate Solr servers can have internal replication or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason I expect you'd want bi-directional replication would be to support something like a cross-datacenter situation. That is, you want to isolate queries to particular places, but keep things in sync across a high-latency link.

If you don't need this, just use SolrCloud and let it handle replication. You can shard your index and get whatever update throughput you need. Any update can go to any node, and Solr will make sure it gets written to the right places.

If you are really thinking about datacenters, Solr added some brand new data center support in 6.0, which you can read about here: https://sematext.com/blog/2016/04/20/solr-6-datacenter-replication/
However, this still assumes updating to a single data center and just having the other just follow along.
Apple also did a talk about their (internal) bidirectional replication system you can watch here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Erkln5WWLw 
That said, the simplest thing would just to be to write the updates to both places.

Comment: thanks. do you think that SolrCloud https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud would be a solution? The goal is to have two tomcat servers and if one of them fails, we use another tomcat servers and the solver server of the second tomcat server is still up to date. couln't it possible to just have shared folders for two solr instances?

Comment: If you have a SolrCloud cluster with two servers, and create a collection where all shards are on both servers, (replication factor 2) then you should be able to lose either one without losing anything. SolrCloud handles replication, and you can address writes to either server. You'll need a LB in front, or use CloudSolrClient in order to have clients transparently stop using a down server. Also, Solr 5+ stopped shipping WARs in favor of a more application-oriented release, so talking about Tomcat is no longer very appropriate.